# Can I conditionally exclude some elements (code blocks) from rendering to the PDF and ePub outputs when compiling a bookdown document?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, bookdown

RMarkdown knitting creates beautiful html, including animated gifs with R codeblocks like:

```
{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="80%", fig.cap=""}
knitr::include_graphics(path="imagesForRmd/visualSearch/directionOfMotionPopsOut.gif")
```

While such codeblocks work for including images other than gifs in the PDF output of bookdown, animated gifs unsurprisingly yield an error:

Cannot find the file(s): "(imagesForRmd/visualSearch/directionOfMotionPopsOut.gif"

Is there a way to conditionally exclude specific content in my .Rmd files, such as the above codeblock, from the pdf_book and ePub rendering, so that the error does not occur? Then I could create the html version with the animated gifs, and the PDF and ePub without.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's more idiomatic to do this using the chunk option `eval`. As already mentioned, using knitr you may check the output format on knitting. Since `epub` is considered an HTML output format you may do it like this:

````r
```{r, eval = knitr::is_html_output(excludes = "epub")}
knitr::include_url(path = "your_image.gif")
```
````

````r
```{r, eval = knitr::is_latex_output()}
knitr::include_graphics("your_image.png")
```
````

Comment: Agree about it being more idiomatic, but I like the if/else. Also, ePub successfully shows the animated gif, at least on the MacOS ePub reader!

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to write an if/else statement to display the animated GIF in the HTML book, and display a static PNG image in the PDF and other books:

```
if(knitr::is_html_output()) knitr::include_url("images/sample.gif", height = "250px") else knitr::include_graphics("images/sample.png")
```

Comment: That works. But the scaling caused by "height" doesn't work well - it yields a blank area. This avoids that:
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="30%"}
if(knitr::is_html_output()) knitr::include_graphics("movies/colorgrdnt2_2fpsCONVERTED.gif") else knitr::include_graphics("movies/colorgrdnt2_2fpsStatic.png")
```